# Как создать telegram бота с большим количеством токенов

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram, aiogram-3.x

Меня интересует такой вопрос:
как запустить telegram бота с большим количеством токенов?

То есть, чтобы мой бот мог запускать свои копии, используя ТОКЕНЫ.

Пишу через aiogram.

У кого есть опыт в этом или кто знает, как это делается, помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так, просто кидаете экземпляры ботов по одному, в `run_polling` (ну или `start_polling` смотря как вы запускаете)

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher

bot1 = Bot(BOT_TOKEN1)
bot2 = Bot(BOT_TOKEN2)
bot3 = Bot(BOT_TOKEN3)
dp = Dispatcher()

# handlers...


if __name__ == "__main__":
    dp.run_polling(bot1, bot2, bot3)
```

Comment: а для webhook не подскажете?

Comment: @Qqshka https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/blob/dev-3.x/examples/multibot.py https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/blob/dev-3.x/examples/web_app/main.py